# MacOS: Using Bitbucket and Github, SSH Key?

Tags: git, macos, ssh, key, bitbucket

I have been using GitHub for awhile and want to start using Bitbucket because of their free private repos. If I create a new SSH key for Bitbucket, will it erase my SSH key that I'm using for GitHub? In the future, I would like to still use both Github and Bitbucket.

**OS**: macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use same SSH key for both [github](https://github.com/) & [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) then just paste the current SSH key in bitbucket settings as well.

Write the following command in terminal: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. The output of this command is your SSH key which you can add to your bitbucket account.

Comment: On my github settings for SSH keys, it shows the finger print. Is that what I am supposed to copy?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The operating system I'm using is Mac

Comment: Write the following command in terminal: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. The output of this command is your SSH key which you can add to your bitbucket account.

Comment: Hello Anmol, Thank you so much for your help and your quick responses! It works! I was able to test my repos for both Github and BitBucket.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should work with the same ssh key. Remember that the private key is kept on your side, and a RSA public key should be possible to share around to other sites. If the public key is passwordless then there is no issue. If it is password protected then the password on both sites must be the same.

Comment: I'm in my Github settings account and I clicked on SSH key, do I copy the finger print? Is the finger print on Github the RSA public key? Or what is the command that I can pull  my SSH key code for Github in my terminal?

Comment: If you are using linux you would have a .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub. Alternatively if you already have it in github you will see it under the deploy keys menu.  The instructions on how to use it are then given at: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html